# Sticky remove on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have done topbar sticky on desktop view with the help of Jquery but I don't want a sticky top bar on a mobile screen during scroll.

I did topbar sticky with this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(window).scroll(function(){ 
    var sticky = $('#top-header'), 
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if (scroll >= 100) {
      sticky.addClass('fixed'); 
    } else {
      sticky.removeClass('fixed'); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('#top-header'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) {sticky.addClass('fixed'); }
  else {sticky.removeClass('fixed'); }
});
});

Comment: I did topbar sticky with this code

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57767421/edit) your question and add code. Don't post question related information on comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your condition statement:

```
if ((scroll >= 100) && ($(window).width() > /* Mobile screen width */)) {
   sticky.addClass('fixed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add media query using css or you can define screen width for your jQuery code.

```js
 if($(window).width() > 767){
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var sticky = $('#top-header'), 
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
      if (scroll >= 100) {
        sticky.addClass('fixed'); 
      } else {
        sticky.removeClass('fixed'); 
      } 
     }); 
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code and you also need one more condition for mobile device width. using this code you can remove the "fixed" class on resize also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll resize',function(){
    var sticky = $('#top-header');
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(scrollTop >= 200 && windowWidth >= 768){
      sticky.addClass('fixed');
    }else {
      sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```